# Robot_description not found

Tags: ros, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Fuerte using 'sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop'
I can rosmake various packages, including arm_navigation/planning_environment.

However, when I run 'roslaunch planning_environment environment_server.launch', the service cannot find the (presumably PR2) robot model:

...: Robot model '/robot_description' not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?

I thought any required models would have come down with the ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop installation. Unless by side effect, I did not remap 'robot_description'.

Anything else I need to install or configure?

Thanks!

Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34705/robot_description-not-found/) by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on 2012-05-26**:
The problem ended up being libmysql.so missing various symbols. This defect then prevented Gazebo from initializing properly. Re-installing libmysqlclient16 made the problem disappear. Unclear how the defective library came down. (Thanks to Lorenz for the answer, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you upload a robot description to the parameter server? Normally, you execute the planning launch file when you either have a real robot or simulation running. You can also upload the robot description with

```
roslaunch pr2_description upload_pr2.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6